# Why my Facebook business page is not showing Ratings?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have created my Facebook page a month ago, My clients want to give me reviews but they are not able to access the feature of ratings. So they all left me with recommendations. I received couple of recommendations but My page is still not showing any ratings at all to public. I can still see recommendations when I clicked in the review tab but General public still sees as 0 ratings.

It says you have not received enough recommendations to count your ratings. I have seen many pages that have only 1 recommendations but still showing ratings? But my page still says 0/5 ratings and 0 recommendations. I have double checked tons of times, All the reviews options and tabs from the settings are On and visible to public.

Why my followers are not able to see my ratings?

I am not able to contact Facebook  admins as they have no such criteria. I have reported this as a problem many times but got no response.

Answer (score -1):

I have been struggling with the same. On my FB page, I have more than 30 reviews, but it says 0 reviews 0 rating and I have been trying to contact FB help, without any luck. Would be happy if anyone has an answer here

Answer (score -2):

I’m experiencing the same problem and Facebook are so far useless. I have been posting this message on public pages Facebook for Business, Facebook London and Facebook for Developers. So many people are going thru issues with Facebook and they are sending us around in circles.

Here is my message to Facebook:

I’m trying to get to the bottom of a problem on my business page on Facebook. Help centre and business suite - DO NOT OFFER A SOLUTION.

PLEASE LISTEN AND HELP YOUR CUSTOMERS AND ASSIST US!!!!

My recommendations rating is 0 when it was 5 out of 5 last week. My reviews/recommendations number is now 0 when it’s evident that I have 14 customer recommendations.

Can someone tell me why my rating has gone from 5 to 0 and my page shows 0 recommendations and I have 14?

PLEASE CAN FACEBOOK STOP SENDING US CUSTOMERS AROUND IN CIRCLES WITH A HELP CENTRE THAT DOESNT WORK AND OFFER HANDS ON TECHNICAL SUPPORT TO OUR ISSUES?

Thanks so much [image]